# Синтаксическая ошибка в SQL-запросе

Tags: php, mysql

Запрос:

```
 $query= "INSERT INTO girls_top_month
 (ID, FROM, TO) VALUES
 ('".$_REQUEST['id']."',
'".date('d.m.y')."',
 '".date('d.m.y')."')"; $result =
 mysql_query($query) or
 die(mysql_error());
```

Ответ:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM, TO) VALUES ('7', '05.03.13', '05.03.13')' at line 1

Где я мог опечататься?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FROM - это конструкция SQL. Вероятно нужно сделать вот так

```
 girls_top_month (`ID`, `FROM`, `TO`)
```

Comment: @Damir, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: совершенно верно!  
ТС, обязательно обрамляйте и названия полей тоже в кавычки, чтобы избежать таких проблем в дальнейшем.

Comment: `TO` кстати тоже команда `SQL` ;)

Comment: Не помогло, You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''ID', 'FROM', 'TO') VALUES ('7', '05.03.13', '05.03.13')' at line 1

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку с форматированием кода :)

Comment: Использовали символы ковычек, которые на букве Ё или ~ ?

Comment: Вот таким запросом вставилась запись через phpmyadmin

INSERT INTO  `girlsp`.`girls_top_month` (
`ID` ,
`FROM` ,
`TO`
)
VALUES (
'1232',  '04.03.2013',  '04.03.2013'
);

Comment: Кавычки просто вместо ' поменяйте на `   
INSERT INTO  girlsp.girls_top_month ( `ID` , `FROM` , `TO` ) VALUES ( '1232', '04.03.2013', '04.03.2013' ); .как указал @Damir

Comment: Спасибо, дело было в кавычках :)

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте сделать вот так:

```
$itDate = date('d.m.y');
$reqID = $_REQUEST['id'];
$query= "INSERT INTO girls_top_month (ID, FROM, TO) VALUES ('$reqID', '$itDate','$itDate')";
```